# The usefulness of the useless (pure math and pure science)

Tags: philosophy-of-science, utilitarianism

In Italian philosopher Nuccio Ordine's The utility of the useless, he returns to a traditional and inexhaustible theme: the value of education and its relationship with culture. Ordine identifies that we are experiencing a deep cultural crisis that affects the School and the University. Both suffer from the advance of a utilitarian, practicalist and productivist mentality, motivated by the relentless logic of profit. Such spaces, which should be of intellectual and humanistic formation, become capitalist companies in forming critical and free thinking citizens, but specialized labor for the labor market and consumption.

The text I sent above is just support to ask what I'm looking for: could someone list me articles that comment on this issue? Specifically, I would like to know if there are any other thoughts or articles/materials commenting on the "usefulness of "useless" in pure science and pure math.

Comment: G. H. Hardy, *A Mathematician's Apology*, 1940, is a classic with its article in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematician%27s_Apology

Comment: Often, apparently useless knowledge becomes useful laster. For example, pure number theory has now found applications in cryptography.  Ramanujan's formulae, earlier admired mostly for their elegance, are now being used to understand black-holes.

Comment: The sentiment has a long beard. [Bradley, The Utility of the Useless (1917)](https://www.nature.com/articles/100176b0.pdf), [Flexner, The Usefulness of Useless Knowledge (1939)](https://www.ias.edu/sites/default/files/library/UsefulnessHarpers.pdf), [Wigner,  Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences (1960)](https://web.njit.edu/~akansu/PAPERS/The%20Unreasonable%20Effectiveness%20of%20Mathematics%20(EP%20Wigner).pdf).